# Hyperref Working; Need to add additional cover page bookmark, not included in the contents

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Currently `\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}` is working. PDFs I've viewed in the past, however, include bookmarks for pages prior to the Contents (e.g. Cover, Copyright, etc.) Is there a way to add a bookmark such that these pages (Cover, Copyright, etc.) can be referenced without a prior tag such as `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is the command `\pdfbookmark[level]{text}{anchor}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \pdfbookmark[0]{Cover}{cover}
  % Cover pages
  \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```